# Как передать какие-то значения в функцию обработчик событий?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, события

Для обработки событий использую этот пример:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def keys(event):
    if event.keycode==88: # Клавиша с буквой Ч и с англ. буквой X
        print("Ура! Вы нажали Ctrl-Ч! (Или Ctrl-X)")
root.bind("<Control-KeyPress>",keys)
root.mainloop()
```

Надо сделать так, чтобы в функцию обработки событий можно было передать значение переменной

Пробовал добавить переменную в `def keys(event):` и в `root.bind("<Control-KeyPress>",keys)`, но тогда начинает писать что не хватает `event`.

Как можно передать в функцию обработки событий(`keys`) какие-то значения или как получить значение `event`, необходимое для этой функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо передачи ссылки на функцию, нужно использовать другую функцию, что вызовет первую, например лямбду.

В `my_value` будет значение `"123"`:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def keys(event, my_value):
    if event.keycode==88: # Клавиша с буквой Ч и с англ. буквой X
        print("Ура! Вы нажали Ctrl-Ч! (Или Ctrl-X)")
root.bind("<Control-KeyPress>", lambda event: keys(event, "123"))
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

События можно перехватывать с помощью `lambda event:` и потом вставлять в обработчик.

Пример:
    from tkinter import *
    root = Tk()

```
btn = Button(root, text='Открыть окно', command = lambda: new_window())#Кнопка для открытия окна
btn.pack()

#Функция открытия окна
def new_window():
    self = Toplevel()
    self.focus_force()
    self.bind("<Control-KeyPress>", lambda event: keys(event, self))#`lambda event:` перехватывает событие и передаёт его в обработчик вместе с self 

#Обработчик события
def keys(event, self):
    if event.keycode==88: # Клавиша с буквой Ч и с англ. буквой X
        print("Ура! Вы нажали Ctrl-Ч! (Или Ctrl-X)")
        print('Закрытие окна')
        self.destroy()#Удаление окна
root.mainloop()
```